# can I have multiple realm files?

Tags: react-native, realm

I am using realm for a react native application I am working on. And, one of my use cases is there should be different realm files for different users. I was wondering if realm supports multiple realms cases. If so, how can I name the realm files?

Can someone please let me know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. I can recommend reading the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#realms) on how to do that ;-)

```
// Open a realm at another path
let realmAtAnotherPath = new Realm({
  path: 'anotherRealm.realm',
  schema: [CarSchema]
});
```